# How to display 'higher' unicode letters using Mono on Raspbian?

Tags: c#, unicode, mono, raspbian

I've written a C# application (using VS) and in general it works fine on a Raspi using Mono to run the exe. Now I need a Chinese version, but Mono will not display code points like U+34B5.

I'm quite sure Mono causes the problem, because running everything on Windows works fine displaying the right symbols, and when I open the language csv on the Raspi using a simple text editor, I see the correct symbols, too.

I'm using the same font in my app as in the text editor. I tried lable, textbox aswell as richttextbox. no success.

```
string str = "\u34B4 \u34B5 \u34B6";

TextBox1.Text = str;
```

I'd expect those nice little symbols to be displayed like on windows, but on the Raspi I only see small empty boxes.

Comment: This problem could be related to the `Font` of the UI. Try another fonts,

Comment: Thank you for the hint! But I already tried several fonts. I even installed ARIALUNI.ttf (over 22MB) and tried it. Nothing helps. And as I mentioned above: When opening the csv language file using the default Raspi text editor with the same font I set in the UI, the Chinese symbols get displayed correctly. Could you recommend a certain font and perhaps where to get it from?

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad in the meanwhile I found out that code points e.g. U+4E32 and U+8765 are working with Arial Unicode MS. It looks as if you are right and only CJK Unified 4E00..9FFF are included in ARIALUNI.tff... I need to find out what 'letters' my client really requires. Thank you again!

Comment: you're welcome. There are a couple of websites that help you find fonts, check this :https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/char/4E32-cjk-unified-ideograph-u4e32